# jQuery body click slide up

Tags: jquery

I have a tag, and setted `slideUp` and `slideDown` by jquery. Now I want to slide up the `div` on body click or outer click

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery(".happening").click(function() {
            if (jQuery(".happening").hasClass("bg")) {
                jQuery(".happening").removeClass("bg");
                jQuery(".happening_text").slideUp("fast");
            } else {
                jQuery(".happening").addClass("bg");
                jQuery(".happening_text").slideDown("fast");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way of doing this will be

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    if ($(event.target).attr('class') != 'happening' && !$('.happening').find(e.target).length) {
      if (jQuery(".happening").hasClass("bg")) {
        jQuery(".happening").removeClass("bg");
        jQuery(".happening_text").slideUp("fast");
      }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("body").click(function(event){
   var s=$(event.target).attr("class");

   if(s == "condition1" || s == "condition2" )
   {
    //result
   }
   else if(s == "condition1" || s == "condition2" )
   {
    //result
   }
});
```